# How do I calculate the THD of a given spectrum analyzer waveform?

Tags: spectrum-analyzer, thd

The spectrum analyzer reference level is 0 dBm.
The fundamental level is 3.16 dBm.
The second harmonic value is -9.51 dBm.
The third is -10 dBm.
4th is -19.89 dBm.
5th is -25.32 dBm.
6th is -23.46 dBm.
7th is -28.35 dBm, 
and 8th is -30.68 dBm. 
The attenuation level is 40 dB. 
The attached image is not related to the values. However when I attach the same signal to the automatic distortion meter, it shows 0.04%. There is a conflict between these values. What is the correct method? [image: Sample spectrum analyzer image]

Comment: Normalize all the harmonics (compute them as linear, not log, ratios to the 1st.) Then sum their squares. Then take the square root. Done. Your THD is pretty high, I'm betting.

Comment: Ah. Forgot to add. Do ***not*** add "1" to all that before taking the square root. Only take the (2nd/1st)^2 + (3rd/1st)^2 + ... before taking the square root. Obviously, the 1st isn't included in the sum. Just to be clear.

Comment: Second harmonic is only about 13 dB down, so your THD, without having to add all the contributions, is way, way more than 0.04%. Are you overloading the SA? Reduce the signal and see if the harmonics fall. Is the SA upsetting your amplifier? Even harmonics suggest DC problems, is the SA DC-coupled and pulling bias current from your amplifier? Does your distortion meter expect a different frequency, and that 0.04% is 'no reading' + noise floor? Distort your signal into the distortion meter. Alter the signal level into the SA. You disagree on ref level, you say 0dBm, SA says 30dBm???